# How to change Google Map api v2 polyline in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing application with Google Maps v2, and I want to change the style of polyline in map. I tried inheriting from `Polyline` class but the class is `final` and it didn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: change the style how?

Comment: i want to have an arrow line instead of simple line

Comment: well you cannot extend Polyline so you need to do something with either GroundOverlay and trying on that or drawing on a view on top of the map. or use markers as the arrow

Answer (score 1):

Use the PolylineOptions class to add polylines to the google map api v2.  Simply set the color and width;

```
public int lineColor = 0xFF0000FF;
public int width = 5;

PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions();
po.color(lineColor);
po.width(width);
```

Comment: i tried this, but it change color and width of line, i want to change the look, for example i like doted line, is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without a hack.  Color and width are the only things PolylineOptions supports.  Good Luck with your project.

Comment: But i want to change it, how can i hack it ?